# How to switch between dark and light ttk theme?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

How do I switch between ttk themes?
I tried this:

```py
style = ttk.Style(root)
root.tk.call('source', r'Azure-ttk-theme\azure dark\azure_dark.tcl')
root.tk.call('source', r'Azure-ttk-theme\azure\azure.tcl')
style.theme_use('azure')
```

I created a style, then when a button is pressed, this function is executed:

```py
def change_theme():
    if style.theme_use() == 'azure':
        style.theme_use('azure_dark')
    else:
        style.theme_use('azure')
```

But this doesn't work as expected, the background color of the window does not change:

With light theme:

[image: Light theme]

After changing to dark theme:

[image: only button changes]

It does not change properly.

But it's supposed to look like this after changing theme:
[image: dark theme]

Comment: Does it turn back white when you click again ? Full code would be more helpful or at least the parts that are concerned here.

Comment: @dossimusmaximus Yes, it turns back white. The code concerned with styles and changing it is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've also noticed that inserting line `dark_style.theme_use('azure_dark')` after `light_style.theme_use('azure')` has the same problem as in image 2.

Comment: Okey just wanted to see if you're assigning a style to the widgets but you're just changing the ttk main style ? Well it could work to create a `ttk.Frame` and adding your widgets to it instead of the root frame.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if the Tk object (named root in your case) has a style which can be changed, I know that the background can be changed though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example with default styles:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

def change_theme():
    if style.theme_use() == 'alt':
        style.theme_use('clam')
        root.configure(background='grey')
    else:
        style.theme_use('alt')
        root.configure(background='white')

root = tkinter.Tk()
#root.tk.call('source', r'Azure-ttk-theme\azure dark\azure_dark.tcl')
#root.tk.call('source', r'Azure-ttk-theme\azure\azure.tcl')

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('alt')

frame = ttk.Frame(root).grid()

btn = ttk.Button(frame, text="Sample", command=lambda: change_theme())
btn.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Uncomment those style fetches and change `'alt'` and `'clam'` to `'azure'` and `'azure_dark'` and it should work.

Comment: Same Problem. : [Here](https://imgur.com/a/SJ1NPUb)

Comment: The `style` parameter accepts type `str`, and on passing `azure` or `alt` to `style`, error is raised `Layout alt not found`

Comment: How about with this ? (made changes to the answer)

Comment: Lol. Changing the bg color it is.  Thanks

Comment: I am sure this can be done better by somehow just changing the style values, but this gets the job done at least :D

Answer (score 0):

Try `root.tk_setPalette( "#555555" )` or any color you like.

Themes will not change color but will just change widget styles, especially `Scrollbars`.